# How to straighten a line Shape in Word so that it's perfectly vertical or horizontal after you've moved either endpoint (Word bug workaround)

Tags: microsoft-word, bug, shapes

I saw this question answered previously with "You need to set the width/height to 0", which is 100% correct, but not possible to do in newer Word versions (at least not that I see - it seems you can only set the Line Width now, which is the thickness of the line, not the width of the shape), so I wrote code to do it.

To get it working for you, add these to a module in your Normal template (or add-in):

```
Sub Line_Make_Vertical()
    Dim shpA As Shape
    
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set shpA = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    If shpA.Type = msoLine Then
        If shpA.Height = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Line currently has zero height, so can't also set it to zero width!", vbCritical, "ERROR"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        shpA.Width = 0
    Else
        MsgBox "The selected Shape isn't a line!"
    End If
    
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    ShowErrorMsg Err, "Line_Make_Vertical", "modShapeHelp"
End Sub

Sub Line_Make_Horizontal()
    Dim shpA As Shape
    
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set shpA = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    If shpA.Type = msoLine Then
        If shpA.Width = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Line is currently zero width, so can't also set it to zero height!", vbCritical, "ERROR"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        shpA.Height = 0
    Else
        MsgBox "The selected Shape isn't a line!"
    End If
    
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    ShowErrorMsg Err, "Line_Make_Horizontal", "modShapeHelp"
End Sub
```

Note I named the Module "modShapeHelp".

I'm also including my Error Message subroutine, as they call it:

```
Public Const ADMIN As String = "xxxxxxxxx"

Public Sub ShowErrorMsg(errThis As ErrObject, strSubName As String, strModName As String _
    , Optional vbMBStyle As VbMsgBoxStyle = vbCritical, Optional sExtraText As String = "")
    If errThis.Number <> 0 Then
       MsgBox "An Error Has Occurred in the Add-in.  Please inform " & ADMIN & " of this problem." _
            & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
            & "Error #:              " & errThis.Number & vbCrLf _
            & "Description: " & "     " & errThis.Description & vbCrLf _
            & "Subroutine: " & "      " & strSubName & vbCrLf _
            & "Module: " & "           " & strModName & vbCrLf _
            & "Source: " & "            " & errThis.Source & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
            & IIf(sExtraText = "", "", sExtraText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf) _
            & "Click OK to continue." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
            & "NOTE: Pressing CTRL-C copies this message to the Clipboard," & vbCrLf _
            & "after which pressing CTRL-V will paste it into an email or other" & vbCrLf _
            & "destination!", vbMBStyle Or vbSystemModal
    End If
End Sub
```

If using the Normal template, simply customize your ribbon to add a new top-level ribbon (or group in an existing ribbon, or put it wherever you want of course) and add these two to that Group from the "Macros" list. I rename them "Line - Make Vertical" and "Line - Make Horizontal".

[Ribbon Customization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4zIX.png)

Comment: Please uncouple your answer from the question. Currently your post contains both, but the answer needs to be an answer, not a question.

Answer (score 2):

The simple method is to move the endpoint of the line while holding
the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

Word will then constrain the line to be either totally horizontal or
vertical, according to the direction in which you move the cursor.

Comment: There was, and still may be in some versions, a bug that does not let you do this. The latest versions do not seem to have the bug, but there may still be versions in use that need the code given.

Answer (score 0):

A few things here:

1. Not sure how you inserted the line, but even in the most recent version I do have the height and width fields for the line "size".
2. As harrymc already wrote, you are best of using <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. Not only when you insert the line the first time, but also whenever you change it's length by using the end points of the line
3. It can be the case, that you might want to angle a line. In that case, don't just use the end points of the line to change its angle. Rather open the dialog window in the size section and the enter a proper value for the angle. Like that, you could later change that angle back to 0° and the line will be "straight" again. Note, that dragging the end points of a line won't change the angle value of it, so you'll always need to go through the dialog window.